# Loading wordpress from /var/www file in a mozilla firefox browser

Tags: html, css, wordpress-theming

I was trying to create a website using wordpress. So I have copied wordpress to /var/www file. I downloaded a new theme and activated that. After doing so when I tried http://localhost/wordpress url on my browser a blank page appeared and I couldn't edit or change the theme.

Thanking you.

Answer (score 0):

Go to this link and change the theme

http://localhost/wordpress/wp-admin